# Minimize spectral norm under diagonal similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

Let $A$ be a real square matrix of size $n \times n$. Is there an upper bound on the minimum spectral norm under diagonal similarity, i.e.,

$$
s(A) = \min_{D} \lVert D^{-1} A D\rVert_2,
$$ 
where $D$ is a non-singular, diagonal real matrix. Also, is there are a relation between $s(A)$ and the spectral radius $\rho(A)$?

For the numerical radius $r(A) = \max_{\lVert x \rVert_2 = 1} \lVert \langle Ax, x\rangle \rVert$, [it is](http://www.cscamm.umd.edu/tadmor/pub/linear-stability/GTZ%20spectral%20matrices%20LMA75.pdf)

$$\rho(A) \leq r(A) \leq \lVert A\rVert_2 \leq 2 r(A).$$

I was hoping that it may be possible to minimize $r(D^{-1} A D)$.

Comment: Do you have any reason to expect a simpler expression for $s(A)$ than the definition?

Comment: @MarkMeckes There are few: 1) special case of a triangular matrix $T$, where $s(T) = \rho(T)$. 2) there should be at least bounds related to the numerical radius.

Comment: 1) It's hard to get anywhere from the triangular case for non-unitarily invariant quantities. 2) Okay, bounds should be findable. Phrasing the question as "What is ...?" makes it sound like you want an exact expression.

Comment: @MarkMeckes Sorry, for the implication. I'm happy with a bound.

Comment: Denis's answer gives you $\rho(A) \le s(A) \le \| A \|_2$.  Is that good enough for your purposes?

Comment: @MarkMeckes Isn't this bound clear from $D$ being the identity matrix? As in the triangular case, $|| T ||_2$ can be arbitrarily large compared to $\rho(T)$, which is not enough, I'm afraid.

Comment: The second bound is clear; it's the first one that's nontrivial.  I take it you're mostly interested in an *upper* bound on $s(A)$ in terms of $\rho(A)$.

Comment: @MarkMeckes Missed this. Yes I need an upper bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get an upper bound in general in terms of the spectral radius $\rho(A)$.  Counterexample: if
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} x & 1 \\ -x^2 & -x \end{bmatrix}
$$
then $\rho(A) = 0$ and $s(A) = 2|x|$.  (This $A$ is essentially the most general $2\times 2$ matrix whose eigenvalues are both $0$.)

Comment: That is very insightful! Ok, so the upper bound is futile. Any good idea on how to compute $s(A)$ numerically? But, this is then a new question, I guess.

Comment: @SebastianSchlecht: That would be both a new question, and one that is outside my expertise.

Answer (score 3):

The norm $A\mapsto s(A)$ has the flaw of not being unitarily invariant. However, if you think that every $P\in{\bf GL}_n({\mathbb R})$ can be factorized out $P=UDV$ where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal, you obtain
$$\inf\{s(U^TAU)\,;\,U\in {\bf O}_n\}=\inf\{\|P^{-1}AP\|_2\,;\,P\in{\bf GL}_n({\mathbb R})\}=\rho(A).$$
The second inequality is a rather well-known fact. It can be used in the proof of Householder Theorem. See my book on matrices (Springer-Verlag GTM**216**).

Comment: Thank you very much for this. As discussed with Mark Meckes above, I need rather an upper bound for $s(A)$. I have adjusted the question accordingly.