# Minimize Frobenius instead of Spectral norm via diagonal similarity

Tags: linear-algebra

Given square matrix $A$. I am looking for a numerical solution for 
$$
s(A) = \inf_D \| D^{-1} A D\|_2,
$$ 
where $D$ is a non-singular, diagonal real matrix. A numerical solution was [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306684/numerical-minimization-spectral-norm-under-diagonal-similarity). However, simpler numerical methods exist for minimizing the Frobenius norm:
$$
f(A) = \inf_D \| D^{-1} A D\|_F.
$$ 
I am wondering, how far the solutions of the Frobenius problem (scaling matrix $D_F$) can diverge from the optimal solution:
$$
\varepsilon = \| s(A) - \| D_F^{-1} A D_F \|_2 \|.
$$
For instance, if $A = D^{-1} U D$ with unitary $U$ and diagonal $D$ than $\varepsilon = 0$. Same holds for reducible matrices, e.g., triangular matrices. What is a case, where this doesn't work?